# NetBeans try open new instance from FileZilla

Tags: netbeans, filezilla

I have configured FileZilla to use `php /home/user/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans` for opening php files with netbeans, the problem I have is that FileZilla tries to open those files in a new instance of NetBeans, not in the current opened.

My system is Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Yeah, I'm interrested in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have netbeans opened beforehand. This works for me. No new instances with filezilla.

This was driving me nuts!!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure FileZilla > Edit > Setting > File Editing 
paste your exe path like:

php "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin\netbeans.exe" -open

other than this link may help you

http://ubuntu.findincity.net/view/635400140124705175335766/netbeans-wont-open-filezilla-files